# Asterisk 13.0.1 with Freepbx 12.0.13 - Call Recordings

Tags: asterisk, audio-recording

I'm using Asterisk 13.0.1 with Freepbx 12.0.13.
When I'm trying to record a call (internal & external),
a file is created in the monitor folder and shows up in the `cdr` and user control panel.
The problem is that the file is "empty".
It is always a 0 seconds recording, nothing is actually being recorded.

This is a clean installation with no "heavy" configuration changes.

I've checked to see if the trunk, outbound rout and extensions have the right settings to allow recording, and they all do.

What could be the issue?

Comment: what do you use mixmonitor command ?  the other possibility is codecs licensing (g729).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this 30 seconds after posting.
I forgot I set g729 as the default codec in my sip settings, and I don't have a translation from g729 to any other codec installed.
After I set the calls to be made using alaw and ulaw codecs the recordings were fine.

Thank you for the quick response!